# Parsing Skype logs

Tags: regex, parsing, csv, export, skype

I found a .dbb file, contactgroup256.dbb , and would like to read it.  Can I load it into MySQL somehow?  There's a [python script](http://cyrenity.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/retrieve-skype-contact-photos-using-python/) to grab contact photos, but I was looking for just the name and phone numbers (text data).

Comment: Maybe this link will help you : http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/231-Skype-Logs.html

Answer (score 1):

I think [this open source tool](https://github.com/Vayu/skypelog/) should have what you need.
From the description:

> skypelog.py -- read and save Skype Linux chat history in Python.
>
> Skype for Linux stores user chat history in binary *.dbb files.
> skypelog.py implements classes to easily access data in these file in Python.